# How can I close an element created by document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I write this:

```
document.createElement("img")
```

The generated html is: `<img>`, and I can add attributes on this element. However, is there a parameter or something I could pass to createElement to make it self-closing? Or is there a dom function I could call to generate the `</a>` closing tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't matter if tags are self-closing or not when they've been processed by the DOM. If you type `<img/>` in the source and then look at `innerHTML`, you'll see `<img>` instead.

Similarly, you don't need to "generate" the closing tag because it's already there. The browser has already taken your text-based HTML and turned it into a tree of nodes. Using DOM functions affects the tree, and getting `innerHTML` just turns it into one of many possible text formats that produce the same tree.

Comment: @Dave HTML5, like older versions of HTML, still doesn't have self-closing tags.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean xhtml. Can it self close to show <br /> instead of <br>

Comment: I don't know, if I'm honest, but I would assume that `innerHTML` returns HTML, not XHTML. So no self-closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

It happens automatically when you append the element somewhere.

Like this:

```
 var newElem = document.createElement ("div");
 newElem.innerHTML = "sample text";
 newElem.style.color = "red";

 var container = document.getElementById ("container");
 container.appendChild (newElem);
 //the container contains a closing div tag
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakHt/

Answer (score 0):

The DOM structure has no real notions of *tags* as HTML markup. All that data has been deserialised and turned into a structure.

Answer (score 0):

Once you append it to body(DOM), browser will automatically closes it .